# Dynamic dispatching messages design consultation

Tags: java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, architecture, jms

I have a design question and would like to have suggestions.

I am using Weblogic 11g, EJB3.0

I have a system which it's target to retrieve and dispatch messages to couple of resources(databases).

Each message contain information and target database key.

So here is an flow example:

I get from web service a message and key target. I parse the message and dispatch it to the right database via the key target.

There is a possibility that a message will contain more then one target database.(for example the key 'all' means that I should dispatch to all databases.

If Insert is failing in one of the resources a rollback will occurred and I a re-try will re-execute the whole operation.

So now this is my issue:

Should I make the number of the queues as the number of my resources? (and dedicated each Queue to a specific resource)

(In this case I parse each message and just send it to the right queue while an MDB will listen and do the insertion to the right database)

If I do it that way I wont be able to make it **dynamic**, Meaning each time a new resource will need to be added/removed in the **future** I will need to open the code and make the right changes.

What you desgigners think? How could I implement it better dynamiclly?

thanks for your help
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using a queue for each destination resource (database) is fine.  And you should not need to change code to add and remove these endpoints as long as they are driven from a configuration file.  Your dispatcher should have a config that lists the destination queue for each "target database key".  The processes/components that read monitor the endpoint queue similarly need configuration such as db connect string or whatever.

Now, adding a adding a new **resource type**, that would require you to rev your code.  But that is to be expected.

Comment: So you saying basically that a config file will list all queues i am using? you talk about xml/text file? sometimes I need also to set different annotations when I config the queue with properties. not sure it can be written dynamically .

Comment: If you truely cannot use a config because the code that configs and writes to the queue is completely unique (can you detect my doubt :) ) then I'd push that code into a QueueConfigurator class (or rather subclass) that can be loaded dynamically and the information it takes to load the configurator should be stored in the config file instead.  That way you can drop in new queue support without recompiling the base.

Comment: I get you. one more thing. i understand that I cant totally avoid "touching" the code since in the future when a new target db key will be added I will need to implement different insertions and logic to the code which will be demanded by the new db. How would you suggest me to design the code efficiently so It will be comfortable to add new "queue tunnels". in a plug able way. thanks.

Comment: Ideally your config can store the insert SQL, the msg fields, etc such that in respinse to receiving a message, the q-to-db handler just reads a msg, looks up the db connection info, looks up the base SQL to use, looks up the msg-to-column mapping, applies them to the SQL, and then executes the statement.